# Disable bugsnag on certain instances

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, bugsnag

I'm trying to use bugsnag for Laravel 5. I got some instances of my application: local, a couple of production, testing etc.

In this https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel documentation it says that I need to replace the Exception handler to Bugsnag handler. But how can I disable Bugsnag for some of my instances?

I made an .env file where I put the apikey, so it'd cool not to use Bugsnag if I don't have that key set (for example).

Right now each instance I create needs apikey or it won't work, and this is a little bin inconvenient. Also, if I put Bugsnag notifications inside my code, what would be the best way to use them only if the env/config var is set, I guess manually checking is not a good idea.

Comment: Did you by chance read step 3 in the Configuration for Laravel 5 section at that link?  I think best practice would be to use bugsnag all the time, just don't send any data to the API unless in production.

Comment: Well, yes, good point. Still I don't think that it's that flexible though, I'd prefer some kind of BUGSNAG_ENABLE=true variable in the .env file, or something like that.

Comment: @Victor did you find a fix to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bugsnag has a config option for this now:

`Bugsnag::setNotifyReleaseStages(['development', 'production']);`

This restricts the reporting to the configured environments.

Answer (score 3):

In the file `config/bugsnag.php` you can update this line `'notify_release_stages' => ['production'],`